# Revit Design Automation failedExecution with code -536852669

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I was running a workitem on Design Automation for Revit, and it crashed with code 536852669. Looking at the log, it seems like it had almost finished the job when it crashed:

```
[06/08/2022 20:55:21] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[06/08/2022 20:55:21] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -536852669 which indicates an error.
[06/08/2022 20:55:21] End script phase.
[06/08/2022 20:55:21] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[06/08/2022 20:55:21] Job finished with result FailedExecution
```

The addon is a custom exporter (based on IExportContext) and was processing a relatively large model (7GB of Revit files). Any idea what may have caused the crash?

Comment: Please post the workItem ID so we can identify it

Comment: [06/08/2022 19:28:53] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[rvtFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[Revit2ProtoExporter].path)\""
]
"Settings":{}
"Id":"d7c4a090a5f14b818d1626278be75083"
"ActivityId":"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporterActivity+OV"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Revit_2022!84"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporter!83"
]

Comment: I believe that would be : "Id":"d7c4a090a5f14b818d1626278be75083" ? Let me know if I can add more info.

Comment: Yes, "d7c4a090a5f14b818d1626278be75083" is the id. The failure seems a glitch that EC2 machine processed this WorkItem was killed for some reason. I need to looked into why, but nothing wrong with this WorkItem itself. Please submit the WorkItem again. If it still fails somehow, let me know.

Comment: I tried again and it failed with the same error, seems to be at the exact same place: "Id":"e8fd1290b3ea49e299491b100209cac1"

Comment: As for "e8fd1290b3ea49e299491b100209cac1", the EC2 instance just worked as expected, no termination. But the WorkItem was failed by the execution indeed. The logs didn't show any error though, so I cannot tell what went wrong. Here are what you can do: 1. try the same addin and input file in Desktop Revit with local debugging tool: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-csharp-revit.local.debug.tool to see if the addin can succeed with this big input file; 2. share the activity definition, addin source code and input file with us so we can try to reproduce

Comment: We have been using the same addin for a long time and exporting this model as well. I also had another job(different model) failing with the same error: "Id":"c159814bdbe8443bb08f16d4fd3ddc27"

Comment: Even if the addin works fine, but the inputs are different. I think in this case, your WorkItems failed by running out of memory of the machines. Unfortunately, we don't have workaround for this issue so far

Comment: So I have seen the explicit "OutOfMemorry" exceptions. Should I consider -536852669 and  -1073740791 synonymous ?

Comment: See the comment in the other post. I think both of them are due to running out of memory of the machines. The difference is -536852669 error made EC2 machine down, that was why I cannot read anything in the machine's logs while no error shows up for -1073740791. 
What are the difference in the inputs by -536852669 and -1073740791?