# Revit Design Automation fails on downloading resources

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-data-management

I have been able to run several jobs on Forge, but I am running into a new situation today. It seems like the workitem stays idle for about 70 minutes even when it reports back "In Progress". Finally when the workitem starts, it fails immediately on downloading resources. I am assuming because the signed URL doesn't last that long:

```
[06/10/2022 01:07:09] Starting work item accb10182b02420f925ccd4d113dffbd
[06/10/2022 01:07:09] Start download phase.
[06/10/2022 01:07:09] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/b70c5565-0ff5-48cb-af7b-b3f57113786e?region=US'
[06/10/2022 01:07:10] Embedded resource [{"ViewName": "VR_EXPORT"}] is saved as file: T:\Aces\Jobs\accb10182b02420f925ccd4d113dffbd\params.json.
[06/10/2022 01:07:10] Error: Failed - 404 (Not Found)
Request: GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/b70c5565-0ff5-48cb-af7b-b3f57113786e?region=US
  Response Headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Accept-Encoding, Range, Content-Type
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2022 01:07:10 GMT
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    x-ads-region: US
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Connection: keep-alive
  Response Content Headers:
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 38
  Response Body:
    {"reason":"Signed Resource not found"}
```

Not sure if this is an internal issue with Design Automation or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It says that "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/b70c5565-0ff5-48cb-af7b-b3f57113786e?region=US" cannot be found, not a problem of Design Automation. Could you double check the input url to see if you can download it locally first?

Comment: Here is the signedURL:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/b70c5565-0ff5-48cb-af7b-b3f57113786e?region=US

Comment: Also, I put 300 minutes for minutesExpiration when creating the url

Comment: OK, I looked more. There are two issues here: 1. one issue in Design Automation, which seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552509/revit-design-automation-failedexecution-with-code-536852669, the instance was killed during the WorkItem's running, however, in this case, another EC2 instance started to process the same WorkItem; 2. the signed url seems expired when the 2nd instance tried to download it, 300 mins for minutesExpiration might not work as expected.
I am investigating issue#1.

Comment: Oh I see. that would explain the weirdness with the report that I got.